Given any local homomorphism of local $k$-algebras, show that there is a morphism inducing the given local homomorphism.
Let $U$ and $V$ be quasi-affine varieties. Let
$$\psi : \mathcal{O}_{V,q} \to \mathcal{O}_{U,p}$$
be the given local homomorphism of local $k$-algebra, where local homomorphism means that it is a map of local rings mapping to maximal ideal into maximal ideal.
Show that there exist an open neighborhood of $p$ and a morphism $g : W \to V$ with $g(p) = q$, and inducing $\psi$.
So far what I've done is following

Let $X$ and $Y$ be affine varieties containing $U$ and $V$ as open subsets, respectively.
Let $A(Y) = k[t_1, \dots, t_m]$ be the coordinate ring of $Y$. 
Then we have a map from $A(Y)$ to $\mathcal{O}_{U,p}= \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ given by
$$t_i \mapsto \frac{f_i}{h_i} \text{ where }f_i, h_i \in A(X) \text{ and }h_i(p) \neq 0 \text{ for each } i.$$
Set $h:=h_1 \dots h_m.$ Then the above map induces $A(Y) \to k[X]_h$,
which gives us a morphism
$$g' : D(h) \to Y,$$
since $D(h)$ is affine.
Clearly, this $g'$ induces $\psi$ and $g'(p)=q$. But I cannot restrict the codomain $Y$ to $V$.
How do I proceed?

